# Looping through list and displaying in Gridview

Tags: c#

```
private void btn_läggtill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string namn = txtn.Text;
        double personnr;
        if (!double.TryParse(txtp.Text, out personnr))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("personnummer måste vara ett tal"); return;

        }

        string distrikt = txtd.Text;


        int antal = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(txta.Text, out antal))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Antal måste vara ett tal"); return;

        }

        int nivå = 0;

        if (antal < 50) 
        {
            nivå = 1;
        }
        else if (antal >= 50 && antal <= 99) 
        {
            nivå = 2;
        }
        else if (antal >= 100 && antal <= 199) 
        {
            nivå = 3;
        }
        else 
        { nivå = 4; }



       

        Säljare nySäljare = new Säljare(namn, personnr, distrikt, antal, nivå);

        säljare.Add(nySäljare);
```

//sort list

```
        int[] nivåOrder = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        säljare = säljare.OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(nivåOrder, x.Nivå)).ToList();
```

//output list into gridview

```
        for (int i = 0; i < säljare.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Equals(säljare[i]))
            {
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                dgvViewsäljare.Rows.Add(säljare[i].Namn, säljare[i].Personnr, säljare[i].Distrikt, säljare[i].Antal, säljare[i].Nivå);
            }
        }
```

/*
Every time i click on "btn_läggtill_Click", I want to

1. add a new item into my list  (taking values from textboxes)
2. Sort the list according to variable "nivåOrder"
3. Display the entire list in gridview
4. When I click again I want the list to be refreshed

CURRENT PROBLEMS

1. I can add a new item, but when I click Repeatedly, the SAME row is shown again and
   again.
2. The refreshed list is NOT in order

*/

Answer (score 0):

For sorting the list, if you want to sort by `Nivå`:

```
säljare = säljare.OrderBy(x => x.Nivå).ToList();
```

Then instead of managing rows in the GridView, I think you can just set the data source to the new, ordered list:

```
dgvViewsäljare.DataSource = säljare;
dgvViewsäljare.DataBind();
```

Comment: Databind(); requires an imported package or something? I get an error